# Populate a listview with an alertdialog from database

Tags: android, database, listview, android-alertdialog, items

I'm trying to make a listview which is populated from the database.In the database I enter data with an alert dialog from the same activity as the list is. I have 3 buttons in the alert dialog: save , delete, close. My problem is that, when I click the save button it gives me an Error.

Here is my Liste.class (the activity where is the list):

```
private View.OnClickListener onAdd = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        edit_box();
    }
};
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

        noteId = String.valueOf(id);
        edit_box();
    }   
};
private void edit_box(){

    final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(addView);
    EditText editNote=(EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    if(noteId != null)
    {
        Cursor c = helper.getById(noteId);
        c.moveToFirst();
        editNote.setText(helper.getNote(c));
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){

                    EditText editNote = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            if(noteId==null){
                helper.insert(editNote.getText().toString());
                noteId = null;
            }
            dataset_cursor.requery();
        }           
        });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){

        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            if(noteId == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else{
                helper.delete(noteId);
                noteId=null;
            }
            dataset_cursor.requery();
        }            
    });
    builder.show();
}

class NoteAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

        NoteAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(Liste.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {

        NoteHolder holder = (NoteHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        NoteHolder holder = new NoteHolder(row);

        row.setTag(holder);

        return(row);
    }}
    static class NoteHolder {

            private TextView note = null;
        NoteHolder(View row) {
            note=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.note);
        }
        void populateFrom(Cursor c, DBhelp helper){
            note.setText(helper.getNote(c));
        }
    }
```

Here is a part of my DBHelper class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Notes(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, note TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void insert(String note){

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("note", note);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Notes", "note", cv);
}
public void update(String id, String note) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args={id};
    cv.put("note", note);
    getWritableDatabase().update("Notes", cv, "_id=?", args);
}
public void delete(String id){

    getWritableDatabase().delete("Notes", "_id=?", new String[] {id});
}
public Cursor getAll(){

    return(getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("SELECT _id, note FROM Notes", null));
}
public Cursor getById(String id){

    String[] args={id};
    return(getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("SELECT _id, note FROM Notes WHERE _id=?",
                                args));
}
public String getNote(Cursor c){

    return(c.getString(1));
}
  }
```

**I'm asking everyone of you if you could tell what may be the problem.I sincerely verified all the code but I can't figure it out where I wrote wrong. I would be very grateful if you could give me an advice or, even better, you could tell me what is the problem. Thank you !**

P.S.: Here is the logcat :

```
12-30 12:57:59.079: W/KeyCharacterMap(340): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-30 12:58:00.359: D/AndroidRuntime(340): Shutting down VM
12-30 12:58:00.359: W/dalvikvm(340): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.project.mapshop.Liste$3.onClick(Liste.java:96)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-30 12:58:00.390: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please post your logcat too?

Comment: noteId is set null at the beginning and if is null when you click save you'll enter another line but if it is 3(for exemple) it will save what you'll write over the row with the id 3 in database. If it is null you'll insert a new one but if it is not, you'll update an existing one. When you click an item from the list, noteId's value is changing. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: And at which line,you are getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Have you checked,you are getting proper value in noteId in onclick of your listitem? and yes,also specify at which line,you are getting null pointer exception as i am unable to figure out that from your incomplete logcat.

Comment: At my nullpointer it doesn't gives me a line. But it gives me an error at 96 line, database.reqeury(); from the pozitive button.

Comment: I think,you need to follow this: in onClick of positive button of your dialog,after saving or inserting your data,you should repopulate your listview. And for the purpose of requerying table with updated database,you should use a method of helper which fetches data from a table for you each time you call it. hope,you got my point!